# Diagonal Matrix Exponential in Python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, exponential

I'm writing a numerical algorithm with speed in mind. I've come across the two matrix exponential functions in scipy/numpy (scipy.linalg.expm2, scipy.linalg.expm).  However I have a matrix that I know to be diagonal beforehand. Do these scipy functions check if the matrix is diagonal before they run? Obviously the exponentiation algorithm can be much faster for a diagonal matrix, and I just want to make sure that these are doing something smart with that - if they aren't, is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: I think `scipy.sparse` has some special support for diagonal matrices (stored as a 1-d array holding just the diagonal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a matrix is diagonal, then its exponential can be obtained by just exponentiating every entry on the main diagonal, so you can calculate it by:

```
np.diag(np.exp(np.diag(a)))
```

Comment: off-diagonal elements are not correct. np.exp(0) should be 1. Here you've got 0.

Comment: I think Doug wants the matrix expoential function, not the exponential for each element of an array. It happens to be the same on the diagonal for diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 3):

If you know A is diagonal and you want the k-th power:

```
def dpow(a, k):
    return np.diag(np.diag(a) ** k)
```

Check if a matrix is diagonal:

```
def isdiag(a):
    return np.all(a == np.diag(np.diag(a)))
```

so :

```
def pow(a, k):
    if isdiag(a):
        return dpow(a, k)
    else:
        return np.asmatrix(a) ** k
```

Similarly for exponential (which you can get mathematically from the expansion of a suite of pow) you can do:

```
def dexp(a, k):
    return np.diag(np.exp(np.diag(a)))

def exp(a, k):
    if isdiag(a):
        return dexp(a, k)
    else:
        #use scipy.linalg.expm2 or whatever
```

Comment: Your `isdiag` won't work; or, rather, `if isdiag(a)` won't, because it returns an array of bools.  You'd need to add an `.all()`.  [I don't know if there's a more efficient way inbuilt to test whether a matrix is diagonal, but it wouldn't surprise me.]

Comment: How do you get "same for exponential?"  It's not the same thing... I want k^a, (specifically e^a), not a^k.

Comment: Just made my answer more precise.

Comment: Isn't there a more efficient way to test for diagonality ?

Comment: fixed return; what do you propose as a diagonality test ?

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a tool that can help being faster doing the same as HYRY but by doing it **in-place**:

```
def diagonal(array):
    """ Return a **view** of the diagonal elements of 'array' """
    from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
    return as_strided(array,shape=(min(array.shape),),strides=(sum(array.strides),))

# generate a random diagonal array
d  = np.diag(np.random.random(4000))

# in-place exponent of the diagonal elements
ddiag = diagonal(d)
ddiag[:] = np.exp(ddiag)

# timeit comparison with HYRY's method
%timeit -n10 np.diag(np.exp(np.diag(d)))   
    # out> 10 loops, best of 3: 52.1 ms per loop
%timeit -n10 ddiag = diagonal(d); ddiag[:] = np.exp(ddiag)
    # out> 10 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop
```

Now,

- HYRY's method is quadratic w.r.t the diagonal length (probably because of the new array memory allocation), and so if your matrices are of little dimension, the difference might not be as big.
- you need to be alright with in-place computation
- Finally, the off-diagonal elements are 0, so their exponential should be 1, shouldn't it ? In both our method the off-diagonal are 0.

For that last part, if you want all off-diagonal elements to be 1, then you can do:

```
d2 = np.ones_like(d); 
diagonal(d2)[:] = np.exp(np.diag(d))

print (d2==np.exp(d)).all()  # True
```

But this is linear w.r.t to array size, so quadratic w.r.t to diagonal length. The timeit gives ~90ms for a 4000x4000 array and 22.3ms for a 2000x2000.

Finally, you can also do it in-place to get a little speed up:

```
diag = np.diag(d)
d[:]=1
diagonal(d)[:] = np.exp(diag)
```

Timeit gives 66.1ms for 4000^2 array, and 16.8ms for 2000^2